# Unity зависает при работе с TcpClient (C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

При запуске приложения на юнити осуществляю подключение к серверу:

```
/// <summary>
/// Обработка запуска игры
/// </summary>
public class GameBeginning : MonoBehaviour, Listeners.ConnectionListener
{
    Thread connection;

    void Start()
    {
        // Подключаемся к серверу
        NetworkManager.Instance.addConnectionListener(this);
        connection = new Thread(NetworkManager.Instance.connect);
        connection.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Не удалось подключиться
    /// </summary>
    public void connectionFailed()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connection failed");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Удалось подключиться
    /// </summary>
    public void connected()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected");
    }
}
```

Класс NetworkManager:

```
/// <summary>
/// Менеджер сетевого подключения
/// </summary>
public class NetworkManager : Singleton <NetworkManager>
{

    private string ip = "192.168.1.6";              // ip-адрес сервера
    private int port = 5555;                        // Порт сервера для подключения

    private TcpClient client;                       // Подключение к серверу
    private NetworkStream stream;                   // Поток обмена данными с сервером

    private List<Listeners.ConnectionListener> connectionListeners = new List<Listeners.ConnectionListener>();  // Слушатели события подключения к серверу

    /// <summary>
    /// Соединиться с сервером
    /// </summary>
    public void connect()
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        var result = client.BeginConnect(ip, port, null, null);

        var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(4000);
        if (!client.Connected || !success)
        {
            // Не удалось подключиться
            foreach (Listeners.ConnectionListener listener in connectionListeners)
            {
                listener.connectionFailed();
            }
            return;
        }

        // Удалось подключиться
        client.EndConnect(result);
        foreach (Listeners.ConnectionListener listener in connectionListeners)
        {
            listener.connected();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавить слушателя события подключения к серверу
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listener">новый слушатель</param>
    public void addConnectionListener(Listeners.ConnectionListener listener)
    {
        connectionListeners.Add(listener);
    }
}
```

**Описание проблемы:**
Сервер сейчас выключен. При первом запуске приложения в Unity всё работает корректно, вызывается метод *connectionFailed*. После этого я останавливаю приложение и запускаю его заново, и юнити просто зависает. Даже не открывается окно приложения (вкладка Game) - просто остаётся зажатой кнопка Play.

Если закомментировать строку

```
connection.Start();
```

то всё запускается корректно и несколько раз. Пробовал без потока - всё равно второй запуск кладёт Unity. Объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как избавиться от этой проблемы?

Comment: Если сервер включить при повторной попытке, то все работает как нужно?

Comment: Сейчас поменял ip-адрес на действительный, проверил с работающим и неработающим сервером - всё работает корректно. Получается проблема возникает при повторной попытке подключения по несуществующему ip-адресу.

Comment: @KamoSpertsian ответьте тогда на свой вопрос сами и отметьте его, чтобы другие могли найти ответ на похожий вопрос